# How can I make FutureProducer to perform at least near the performance of ThreadedProducer in rust rdkafka?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm just playing around the examples, and I tried to use FutureProducer with Tokio::spawn, and I'm getting about 11 ms per produce.
1000 messages in 11000ms (11 seconds).

While ThreadedProducer produced 1000000 (1 million messages) in about 4.5 seconds (dev), and 2.6 seconds (on --release) !!!, this is insane difference between the two and maybe I missed something, or I'm not doing something ok.
Why to use FutureProducer if this big speed difference exists?
Maybe someone can shed the light to let me understand and to learn about the FutureProducer.

Kafka topic name is "my-topic" and it has 3 partitions.

Maybe my code is not written in the suitable way (for future producer), I need to produce 1000000 messages / less than 10 seconds using FutureProducer.

My attempts are written in the following gists (I updated this question to add new gists)

---

**Note:**
After I wrote my question I tried to solve my issue by adding different ideas until I succeeded at the 7th attempt

1- spawn blocking:
https://gist.github.com/arkanmgerges/cf1e43ce0b819ebdd1b383d6b51bb049

2- threaded producer
https://gist.github.com/arkanmgerges/15011348ef3f169226f9a47db78c48bd

3- future producer
https://gist.github.com/arkanmgerges/181623f380d05d07086398385609e82e

4- os threads with base producer
https://gist.github.com/arkanmgerges/1e953207d5a46d15754d58f17f573914

5- os thread with future producer
https://gist.github.com/arkanmgerges/2f0bb4ac67d91af0d8519e262caed52d

6- os thread with spawned tokio tasks for the future producer
https://gist.github.com/arkanmgerges/7c696fef6b397b9235564f1266443726

7- tokio multithreading using #[tokio::main] with FutureProducer
https://gist.github.com/arkanmgerges/24e1a1831d62f9c5e079ee06e96a6329

Comment: Multithreading and concurrency (that is, asynchronous programming) do not work in the same way, and therefore do not produce efficient code in the same situations. In particular, concurrency does not parallelize operations, which means that if the bottleneck is CPU-bound (that is, you would have a speed-up by increasing your CPU capacity), then multithreading will be much more helpful than concurrency. The latter is more useful if you are IO-bound (for instance, if the bottleneck is waiting for a message to be delivered on the network).

Comment: The main point being: your problem may simply not be solvable with concurrency, and therefore you'll always to slower with futures / tokio / async. A way to check that out would be to do some profiling: measure what are the resources that are the most used during the creation of your messages.

Comment: Thanks @BlackBeans for the explanation, but the first example 1- spawn blocking is using https://gist.github.com/arkanmgerges/cf1e43ce0b819ebdd1b383d6b51bb049#file-msg_spawn_blocking-rs-L79 "spawn_blocking" which it will create a new os thread as I know from the doc https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.spawn_blocking.html

Comment: Yes, but you should see it the other way around. When doing concurrency, you are **not** doing things in parallel. The difference wrt normal computation is there is a runtime that changes the order in which different parts of your code are executed so that execution matches availability of resources. For instance, if a piece of code needs reading from a file, but the hard disk is currently doing something else, you will *instead* do some other work. This means that in this situation, if a piece of code "blocks" (ie. you `sleep`), you will block the execution of every concurrent code.

Comment: Unless you `yield`, that is, you say that you don't want to do work anymore, and therefore other pieces of code can be executed by the runtime. However, there are situations in which you may want to "block" while doing concurrency. To avoid blocking everything, `tokio` offers a utility that allows you to execute concurrent code in a different thread. The idea is that `tokio` aims at improving IO bound programs, and some IO operations do block. However, this is still having IO bound programs in mind. If you just want to spawn a new thread, just do `thread::spawn`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243956/discussion-between-blackbeans-and-arkan).

Comment: @BlackBeans I've added new test for using os threads with base producer, and I've put the results of the tests as a comments in the top of the gist code

Comment: @BlackBeans I added other 2 examples above, and finally I've used FutureProducer to produce 1 million messages in 4 seconds :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my 5th example, I needed to use os threads (thanks for the discussion with @BlackBeans), and inside the os thread I've used tokio runtime that uses 4 worker thread and which it will block in the os thread.
The example used 100 os threads, and each one has tokio runtime with 4 worker threads.

Each os thread will produce 10000 messages.
The code is not optimized and I ran it in build dev.

---

A new example that I've done in my 7th attempt, which I used #[tokio::main] which is by default will use block_on and when I spawn a new task, it can be put in a new os thread (I've made a separate test to check it using #[tokio::main]) under the main scheduler (inside block_on). And could produced 1 million messages in 2.93 seconds (dev build) and 2.29 seconds (release build)

Answer (score 1):

I think I went through a similar journey: Starting with the FutureProducer because it seemed a good place to start, totally terrible performance. Switching to ThreadedProducer, very fast.

I know Kafka quite well, but a noob at Rust. The FutureProducer is broken, as far as I can see, as every await you call will flush and wait for a confirmation.

That is simply not how Kafka is intended, what makes Kafka fast is that you can keep pumping messages and only occasionally and asynchronously get acks from the current offsets.

I like how you managed to improve thoughput by using many threads, but that is more complex than it should be, and I suppose also much more demanding on both the broker and the client.

If there at least was a batch variant the performance would be bearable, but as I see it now it is suitable for low volume only.

Did you have any insights since you tried this?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts. I didn't try since then, because I was satisfied with the result of 2.29 seconds (release build) :)).